# php array keys/ editing db

Tags: php, arrays

I have one page with multiple inputs named - name='phonenumber[]. I'm sending a form to another page and I like to be able to edit the db with the new post information. How should I write the code, so that for example, I fill the 3rd input and after sending the form, only the 3rd row from the table gets edited. I tryed like this but it won't work:

```
if ($_POST['phonenumber'] || $_POST['phonetype'])
{ 
    foreach($_POST['phonenumber'] as $k => $phonenumber) { 
    $phonetype = $_POST['phonetype'][$k];
    $n = $k+1;
mysql_query("UPDATE phone SET phone_number='$phonenumber', phone_type='$phonetype' WHERE id_user='$id' LIMIT $n");
    }
}
```

This way all the phone numbers gets edited with the information send from the 3rd input POST. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug what $k is?

Comment: if you want to update a column in a row you should be able to pick that row with some unique identifier.if you don't have that identifier jack's solution is the best one,delete and add again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After look like your question, two solutions can be done

1. If phone numbers are individually identifiable like by phone_id column then send that POST DATA and Update through this.

   `mysql_query("UPDATE phone SET phone_number='$phonenumber', phone_type='$phonetype' WHERE id_user='$id' AND phone_id = '$phone_id' ");`
2. If not, then remove all phone number exists for id_user and then re-insert by POST Data.

Comment: Looks like the 1st solution is the one. Thanks. However, how do I pass two id's via url?

Comment: I think best way is change your html field name like that `<input type="text" name="phonenumber[<?php echo $phone_id ?>]";` Then in POSTED data you can get phone id in  foreach loop by key and updated number by value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your phone numbers are not individually identifiable (my guess); at every loop you're updating N rows with the next value, and at the end all entries will have the last value.

Instead, it's usually easier to just delete all phone numbers and re-insert them.

```
DELETE FROM phone WHERE id_user=?

// for loop
INSERT INTO phone (phone_number, phone_type) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE id_user=?
```

Alternatively, if your phone numbers have their own id, include that in the `WHERE` statement when you perform the `UPDATE`; you should definitely remove the `LIMIT`.

Lastly, look into prepared statements (with pdo or mysqli); your current code is susceptible to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Thanks, they do have their own IDs, I just forgot to put them in the WHERE clause.